# Automatically change while query "Case When" in Jasper

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, jasper-reports

I have the data whose type is float. I would like to show them as numeric/integer but for just one case, it will show as a float. For the first i thought with Case When in the query, it will be solved but it didn't happen.

i put this code

`CASE WHEN SUBSTRING (c.kode_hs,1,2) = '71' THEN CAST(c.brutto AS float) ELSE c.brutto END AS brutto,
CASE WHEN SUBSTRING (c.kode_hs,1,2) = '71' THEN CAST(c.netto AS float) ELSE c.netto END AS netto,`

But it didn't turn out to be a float type.
i try to modify the setting of jasper, but it just work for one data type.
There's another alternative i took, i changed the type into number, so that case `CASE WHEN SUBSTRING (c.kode_hs,1,2) = '71'` worked out. But, unfortunately,when its value was highest (or have much character) was shown as scientific number e.x.: 2E9. That look is definitely ignored in report view. Is it any other solution for me? Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You could select the data from the database as it is, as a float, and do the trick in Jasper.
Set the type of c.kode_hs field in JasperReport as Float, ant the ExpresionClass of the TextBox in which you want to show the value as String. Then set the Text Field Expression as

```
$F{kode_hs}.toString().substring(0,2).equals("71")?new java.text.DecimalFormat("#0.00").format($F{brutto}):new java.text.DecimalFormat("##").format($F{brutto})
```

assuming $F{kode_hs} and $F{brutto} are the fields which hold the respective values.